# JavaFX - Automatically update a choiceBox

Tags: javafx, observable

I have a Thread which permantly updates/creates a List:

```
private ObservableList<String> query() {
    try {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(getWMIValue(query, fieldName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList("");
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        devices = query();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WmiAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

public ObservableList<String> getDevices() {
    return devices;
}
```

and i have an JavaFX fxml controller which adds that List to a ChoiceBox

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    wmiAccess = new WmiAccess(
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity", "Name"
    );

    Thread wmiThread = new Thread(wmiAccess);

    wmiThread.start();

    choiceBox.setItems(wmiAccess.getDevices());

}
```

My problem now is: The ChoiceBox isn't updating its content automatically. How do i manage to update the content of the choiceBox to whatever value the 'devices' list holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

First, you are not updating the same list, you're creating a new one every time:

```
while (true) {
    devices = query();
    // ...
}
```

just assigns a new list to the variable `devices` on each iteration. Since the `initialize()` method in the controller just gets the reference once, when you update `devices` to a new list, it is no longer the list referenced from the controller.

You need something along the lines of

```
while (true) {
    devices.setAll(query);
    // ...
}
```

You need to make sure `devices` is properly initialized when that class is instantiated with `devices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`.

At this point, you probably don't need `query()` to return an observable list any more, a regular list will do:

```
private List<String> query() {
    try {
        return getWMIValue(query, filename); // I'm guessing that returns a list...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

The second issue is that your non-terminating loop is running in a background thread. If `devices` is the list of items in a combo box, you can only update it on the FX Application Thread. So you need to do something like

```
while (true) {
    List<String> latestDevices = query();
    Platform.runLater(() -> devices.setAll(latestDevices));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the job but sadly is leading me directly to another problem. Maybe these are dumb questions it's just the first time i ever work with a complex gui sorry in advance. My ChoiceBox is now able to List all devices but once i've choosen one it is directly resettet and the ChoiceBox empty again because the Thread updates the List. How can i prevent my choice from beeing deleted?

Comment: Its done....managed to fix it myself. Used a ComboBox instead of a ChoiceBox. Everthing works now as intended. Thanks again